# The type or namespace name 'VibrationDevice' could not be found

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

I try to implement vibration in my UWP app by following the [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.devices.notification.vibrationdevice.aspx) from the VibrationDevice API reference. I have a new empty project with the following code:

```
using Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification;

...

if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.Devices.Notifications.VibrationDevice"))
{
    VibrationDevice testVibrationDevice = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
    testVibrationDevice.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
}
```

This code throws the following exception

> The type or namespace name 'VibrationDevice' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have searched for someone with the same problem but I have not found anything similar and don't really know how to solve this.

What am I missing?

EDIT: As [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) pointed out in the comments I had forgot to add the Mobile Extension. Now everything works as it should.

Comment: "are you missing an assembly reference?"  Probably.  Use Project > Add Reference > Universal Windows > Extensions > tick "Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP".

Comment: Thank you! That's was it. Didn't realize I had to add an extension. But now when you mentioned it, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just mistyped the namespace string.

> if
>   (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification**s**.VibrationDevice"))

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. The problem seems to be that 'VibrationDevice' doesn't exist in 'Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification'. But I have no idea why